# CMake FindJNI issue on linux

Tags: c++, cmake, java-native-interface, clion

I'm setting up a C++17 project in CLion and i wanted to use java native interface, but here comes the problem. FindJNI.cmake fails with error:
`Could NOT find JNI (missing: JAVA_INCLUDE_PATH JAVA_INCLUDE_PATH2)`

Ive tried to manually set JAVA_INCLUDE_PATH in my CMakeLists.txt using:
`set(JAVA_INCLUDE_PATH "$ENV{JAVA_HOME}/include")` (and the same with PATH2), it only partly solves the problem because then cmake output is `Found JNI: /usr/lib/jvm/default/lib/amd64/libjawt.so`

My CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.14)
project(project1)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)

find_package(JNI REQUIRED)

add_executable(project1 main.cpp)
```

NOTE: I have JAVA_HOME set to `/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk` and java-8-openjdk package installed from AUR.

Comment: Take a look here: http://jnicookbook.owsiak.org/recipe-No-D001/ and here: http://jnicookbook.owsiak.org/recipe-No-D002/

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried adding includes with this one

```
include_directories( ${CMAKE_JAVA_} $ENV{JAVA_HOME}/include $ENV{JAVA_HOME}/include/linux )
```